# Incorrect combinatorics reasoning

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $5$ cows, $8$ roosters, and $10$ pigs on a farm. The farmer wants to pick $4$ animals, and at least $1$ needs to be a cow. He asked his (alleged) prodigious son Smarty how many ways it can be done.

Smarty says "This is so easy." You pick a cow in ${5\choose 1}$ ways and pick $3$ of the remaining $22$ animals in ${22\choose 3}$ ways. So he says the answer is ${5\choose 1}{22\choose 3}$. But the farmer shakes his head in disgust and says this is incorrect.

---

Why is smarty wrong? I would count it in the same way. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Smarty is wrong because more than one cow may be picked. The choice in which they picked Daisy first and then Clover was picked as one of the 22 other animals is wrongly considered different from the pick where Clover was picked first and then Daisy was one of the 22 other animals.

Comment: But I thought the order isn't taken into account with ${n\choose k}$?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe $5+8+10=23$, not $27$. The "$22$ other animals" includes the other cows.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even check. Good point!

Comment: But smarty is picking from $22$ other animals, and that $22$ includes the other cows. So wouldn't this include the other  cases with more than one cow?

Comment: The issue is, as stinkingbishop correctly points out, that when applying the rule of product, the *sequence of choices* is relevant.  Compare the problem to the one where we pick a cow to live in the house as a pet, and then pick three additional animals of any mix of kinds to sleep outside.  By having chosen a *specific* cow in the first step, you incorrectly applied some sort of significance to the fact that it was *that* cow picked at *that* step.  The outcome where Daisy sleeps inside is considered different than the one where Daisy sleeps outside.

Comment: As such, some (*but not all*) of the possible outcomes were counted more than once.  In particular, the outcomes where $k$ cows happened to be selected were counted $k$ times each when they should have all been considered as the same result.

Comment: If you remain unconvinced, consider the problem where we have only four cows and no other animals available.  We wish to count how many ways there are to select four animals where at least one of them is a cow.  The answer should obviously be $1$, but according to your mistaken logic, you might have thought it was $\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{3}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks your explanation helped me a lot.   I can give you check mark if you consolidate the comments in an answer @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz I was trying to come up with an easily enumerated answer with a smaller number of animals, but your example with just four cows is much more concise than anything I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Add $$\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{18}{3}+\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{18}{2}+\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{18}{1}+\dbinom{5}{4}\dbinom{18}{0}$$ because it says at least one must be a cow (so you can have two, three, or four cows picked). The other way to do it: $$\dbinom{23}{4} - \dbinom{18}{4}$$

Comment: Isn't the the ${22\choose 3}$ term choosing from ALL animals? So why wouldn't this cover the case in which more cows (2, 3, 4) can be picked cows too? Why do we need to add all of these cases separately?

Comment: Oops! I assumed Smarty realized that you cannot mix the animals together. I fixed it.

Comment: I see this is the right answer, but why doesn't ${5\choose 1}{22\choose 3}$ equal the same thing? What's wrong with picking $3$ more cows from the other $22$?

Comment: JMoravitz and Stinking Bishop explain.

Comment: @astronomer6353 Your product doesn't work because it says that for each way to pick the first cow, there are $22\choose 3$ ways to pick the other three animals. This leads to double counting. Suppose cow $1$ was picked and cow $2$ was part of the remaining three. That is the same as if cow $2$ was picked and cow $1$ was part of the remaining $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_5$ are the cows, and $R_1,\dots,R_8$ are the roosters and $P_1,\dots,P_{10}$ are the pigs. Here are two ways of carrying out the procedure which results in $\binom{5}1\cdot \binom{22}3$.

- From the cows, choose $C_1$. Then from the other animals, choose $C_3, R_1, P_2$.
- From the cows, choose $C_3$. Then from the other animals, choose $C_1,R_1,P_2$.

Note that these result in the same set of animals, $\{C_1,C_3,R_1,P_2\}$. This set has been overcounted, so $\binom51\cdot\binom{22}3$ is too large.

Here is another way to think about it; by choosing one of the cows, then choosing the other animals, the first chosen cow becomes "special," as it was chosen in a different step of the process then the other cows. Smarty's procedure is therefore not counting subsets of four animals with at least one cow, but is actually counting subsets of four animals with at least one cow *and* where one of the cows is special. The latter is more specific, and can done in more ways.